# Confused with REST and .Net Web Api - Should there be one GET per controller?

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm very confused about the design of my RESTful services!

If I was doing this using vanilla MVC3/4 then I would simply have action methods marked [HTTPGet] etc. and I could have multiple Get's per controller.  I this way I would organise controllers by their "meta group".

I've looked at the Web API MVC4 template and it gives me the automatic translation from an Http GET to the Getxxx() method - but this implies a single Get per controller and organising controllers by object, rather than function...which seems to make some sense.

I see many posts on adding named routes - but this seems to break the natural model of Get, Post, Put, Delete.  If I do that - then aren't I (in essence) just going back to vanilla MVC4?

- Is there any impact on having lots of controllers?
- Am I thinking
  about this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly,

> Is there any impact on having lots of controllers?

No

> Am I thinking about this correctly?

Generally yes.

Default WebAPI/MVc template uses routing that relays on prefixes and naming GetXXX, PostXX.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
     "WithActionApi",
     "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
 );
```

But you can create your own custom routing with action names instead. Then you uses in URL name of your action method and as you've wrote Attributes to set HTTP Verbs like [HttpGet]

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultApi",
    "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { action="DefaultAction", id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
);
[ActionName("DefaultAction")] //Map Action and you can name your method with any text
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "object of id id";
}        

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> ByCategoryId(int id)
{
    return new string[] { "byCategory1", "byCategory2" };
}
```

Comment: Does adding routes "break" REST principles in any way?  Is it better to have a single controller per object - or is there no concept of "better", just "this works, so does that" ?

Comment: No, routing is just a mechanism that ASP.NET MVC uses. How you organize your controllers and actions doesn't care in REST at all. REST priciples are focused on URLs. That could influence how you organize your controllers. But REST doesn't care about concrete business scenario. And I am sure for your concrete business scenario there are multiple ways to organize URLs/Controllers. Just select appropriate for you and that way when your WebAPI service and dependent web apps will be functioning with good performance and clear to understand

Comment: Here is a link for you about how it is better in REST http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html but implementation is anyway up to you and up to your business scenario

Comment: Thanks @Regfor - that article was what has given me the impetus to move from WCF to REST for my current project.

Comment: Final quick q? Is there any reason to use the WebAPI template over the default MVC4 one?

Comment: When hosting Web API together with ASP.NET MVC otherwise there is default template for WebAPI.